# Maximum length of addition line in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a maximum length of a line when adding numbers in VBA? For example in MS Access:

```
 Dim L As Long

    ' this works
    L = 2696 + 2630 + 2860 + 2860 + 2860 + 2860 + 2795 + 2795 + 2630 + 2630 + 2630 + 263

    ' this gives an Overflow error
    L = 2696 + 2630 + 2860 + 2860 + 2860 + 2860 + 2795 + 2795 + 2630 + 2630 + 2630 + 2630

    Debug.Print L
```

I have never seen this documented. Also, it doesn't throw an overflow error in C# in Visual Studio.

Comment: C# and Visual Studio has *nothing* to do with VBA.

Comment: The adds are using integer math (I.e. adding integers *before* assigning to the long), avoid this by casting one of the values to long: `L = 2696& + 2630 + ...`

Comment: Note that in VB.Net an int is 32 bits unlike VBA/6 where they are 16 bits.

Comment: Wondering if this is documented anywhere

Comment: Well any whole number literal < 32768 is of type integer so when you add such numbers the result is going to need to also fit into an integer.  Not sure if that's documented anywhere, the types for literals are defined here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199514.aspx

Comment: An _Overflow Error_ is something else than a _Line too long_ error. The first means a result doesn't fit the left-hand variable, the second would be caught already _before_ the code actually runs by the interpreter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [type of an integer literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199514.aspx) is an `Integer` (Max +32767):

```
?typename(2696)
Integer
```

The result of adding *n* `Integer`s is also of type `Integer`:

```
?typename(2696 + 2630)
Integer
```

As soon as the accumulation exceeds the bounds of an `Integer` you will get an Overflow exception, it does not matter that the variable you are assigning to is a `Long` because the accumulation is performed before the assignment.

The way to fix this is to make one of the values in the addition a `Long` which you can easily do with the `&` Type Suffix:

```
L = 2696& + 2630 + ..
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use type literal:

```
Sub FFF()

    Dim L As Long
    Dim V As Variant

    ' this works
    L = 2696 + 2630 + 2860 + 2860 + 2860 + 2860 + 2795 + 2795 + 2630 + 2630 + 2630 + 263

    ' this DOES NOT give an Overflow error
    V = 2696& + 2630& + 2860& + 2860& + 2860& + 2860& + _
        2795& + 2795& + 2630& + 2630& + 2630& + 2630&

    MsgBox TypeName(V) '//Long

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

It's interesting to note that if you declare your sum variable as `Variant`, then conversion to `Long` is done automatically. For instance, in the following code `sum` variable is `Integer` *before* the last addition - after that it has `Long` type:

```
Sub SSS()

    Dim sum As Variant, arr As Variant, num As Variant

    arr = Array(2696, 2630, 2860, 2860, 2860, 2860, _
                2795, 2795, 2630, 2630, 2630, 2630)

    For Each num In arr
        '// sum is Integer before last addition
        '// and Long - after it
        sum = sum + num
    Next

    MsgBox TypeName(sum) '//Long

End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting, I never realized VB was interpreting each number as an integer first, then trying to store them as a Long. Makes sense.

I do remember reading somewhere, a long time ago, there there's no longer any sense using regular integers in VB because the Intel CPU's internal guts always have to convert 16-bit integers to 32-bit long integers to do math anyway, so declare them as Integer instead of Long is actually not worth bothering. So I've always declared all integers as Long since then.

Comment: @BrianBattles I have updated answer with other details. But I wonder what is the use case of such addition? :)

Comment: Hi Johny...

I dunno, I just found it leftover in some legacy code in an MS Access app where I work and wonder why it threw that error

Comment: @BrianBattles I see 

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the type of one of the elements in the expression, VBA should then use that type. I think literal whole numbers are implicitly Integers (16 bit), could be wrong.

So something like this

```
Dim L As Long
L = 2696& + 2630 + 2860 + 2860 + 2860 + 2860 + 2795 + 2795 + 2630 + 2630 + 2630 + 2630
Debug.Print L, TypeName(L)
```

Or this would work

```
Dim L As Long
L = CLng(2696) + 2630 + 2860 + 2860 + 2860 + 2860 + 2795 + 2795 + 2630 + 2630 + 2630 + 2630
Debug.Print L, TypeName(L)
```